# JPA getResultList() returns BigInteger for MySQL but Integer for Microsoft SQL server

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, jpa

I have following method:

```
Query q = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table1 WHERE column = :column_id " + "UNION " + "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table2 WHERE column = :column_id");
q.setParameter("column_id", column_id);
```

When I want to get the list of counts (which will be 2 rows), I perform this action:

```
List<BigInteger> counts = (List<BigInteger>) q.getResultList();
```

This is working fine in MySQL. But as soon as I connect to MS SQL server, I'm getting a List of Integer objects:

```
List<Integer>
```

Any idea why there is a difference?

Comment: Your title is backwards.

Comment: Which JPA implementation you use?

Comment: Did you try explicity setting the expected return type like `getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table1 WHERE column = :column_id " + "UNION " + "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table2 WHERE column = :column_id",Integer.class);`

Comment: AhamedMustafaM: thanks, I've tested it but I'm getting this exception: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: java.lang.Integer

Answer (score 24, accepted):

JPA defines the return types for JPQL queries, but for native SQL queries you get whatever the database returns.  That is kind of the point with native SQL queries.

Change your code to Number,

```
List<Number> counts = (List<Number>) q.getResultList();
long count = counts.get(0).longValue();
```

Comment: Thanks James, your solution is the fix! :-)

Answer (score 0):

it is defined serverside

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count

"Returns a count of the number of non-NULL values of expr in the rows retrieved by a SELECT statement. The result is a BIGINT value. "

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258232%28v=sql.80%29

"Return Types

int"

Comment: Hmmm ... but isn't JPA just all about separating database layers from processing layers? How can I get a uniform result? I just want to use BigInteger OR Integer. I don't care which one, just 1 :-)

Comment: as AhamedMusatafaM said, did you try 
Query q = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table1 WHERE column = :column_id " + "UNION " + "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table2 WHERE column = :column_id",Integer.class);

Comment: tagtraeumer: if I try that, I'm getting: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: java.lang.Integer